# Android: How to catch api data in app using room database

Tags: java, android, kotlin, caching, android-room

How to cache data that comes from API in the app using the Room DB to make app work well in offline mode?

//This class explains how I insert data to room, but I don't know to update when user open the app for second time

```
private class InsertMain extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Main> {

    private Response main;
    private WeakReference<SplashActivity> activityReference;
    private Exception exceptionToBeThrown;

    public InsertMain(SplashActivity context, Response main) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "جاري تحميل البيانات!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Main doInBackground(Void... mVoids) {
        Main newData;
        if (activityReference.get().responseDao != null) {
            activityReference.get().responseDao.deleteContent(1);
        }
        try {
            activityReference.get().roomDatabase.responseDao().insert(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (activityReference.get() != null) {
            newData = new Gson().fromJson(activityReference.get().roomDatabase.responseDao().getContent(1), new TypeToken<Main>() {
            }.getType());
            return newData;
        } else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Main mMain) {
        super.onPostExecute(mMain);
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(task, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: " then update the data in DB the next time, how can I do that and don't make the user notice it?" Using a losing? Is hard to tell what you want, please expand on your question with expected behavior, also include your effort so far

Comment: do you mean add some code

Comment: hi, do you got the answer. Im trying to do the same thing. Im not sure if I need to add this `AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDbInstance(this.getApplicationContext()); db.coinDao().insertAllCoins();` in the onResponse?